# Any difference between SDL_HWSURFACE and SDL_SWSURFACE concerning speed&performance?

Tags: c++, video, sdl

SDL_HWSURFACE vs. SDL_SWSURFACE
or even SDL_FULLSCREEN ?

What are the pros and cons here? I assume that HW is much faster.

http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlsetvideomode.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SDL Wiki says it best:

SDL_SWSURFACE
SDL will create the surface in system memory. This improves the performance of pixel level access, however you may not be able to take advantage of some types of hardware blitting.

SDL_HWSURFACE
SDL will attempt to create the surface in video memory. This will allow SDL to take advantage of Video->Video blits (which are often accelerated).

My thoughts:

SDL_HWSURFACE won't be much faster than SDL_SWSURFACE, and probably won't be initiated anyway. if you want real speed you should use  [SDL with openGL](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson36/index.php).

SDL_FULLSCREEN has no effect on speed, it will only make SDL attempt to go fullscreen.

Comment: I considered using openGl very often. But I find its learning curve too steep. You have to code too much stuff to get an image on the screen.

Comment: U can use SDL_SWSURFACE fine on modern PCs with 60 fps, if you limit your self on 800x600 resolution(or similar), and only do 2D graphics.